# Session Start and Action Filter for Session Timeout handling In asp.net Mvc4

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**session Start and Action Filter for Session Timeout handling In asp.net Mvc4 ?**

**Create A SessionExpireFilter Class To Inheriting ActionFilterAttribute**

**I am trying to detect when a session is null and then redirect user to the home page once this is done in Action filter Concept**

```
Below code is follow 
    public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
            {
                public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
                {
                    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

                    // check if session is supported
                    if (ctx.Session != null)
                    {
                        // check if a new session id was generated
                        if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
                        {
                            // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                            // have timed out
                            string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                            if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                            {
                                ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Account/JIOLogin");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                }
            }

**To add a with in web.config some changes** 

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="104857600" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" />
    </authentication>
    **<sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>** 
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>

Controller level to apply Attribute is  [SessionExpireFilter] 

[SessionExpireFilter]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        dbEntities1 db = new dbEntities1();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: OK. So what's the specific problem you are facing?